# How to remove links from simple format comments (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments

Currently I am having an issue with removing links from a user comment. So far this is the code:

```
= simple_format(comment.body)
```

The simple format allows paragraph tags and it removes iframes but it does not remove link tags such as:

```
(<a href="test.com">test</a>)
```

The reason why I want to remove links from the view code and not the model/controller side is that their are different comments that I do want to have links available on.

Comment: you need to do `sanitize "<a href='test.com'>test</a>"`..

Comment: `simple_fornat` turns text into `HTML`, but `sanitize` does reverse. And you need the later one.

Comment: The sanitize removes the paragraph tags as well as the anchor tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need this as you wanted to remove link - [`strip_links`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_links)

```
>> helper.strip_links "<a href='test.com'>test</a>"
# => "test"
```

Comment: It removes all paragraph tags as well as the anchor

Comment: use `simple_format(strip_links "<a href='test.com'>test</a>")`

Comment: Thanks! It worked : )    I modified it to = simple_format(strip_links "#{comment.body}")